# How to filter out number and . from text using Excel formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### I have the following text cell values:

```
31.55c/kWh
49.66c/kWh
12.84 cents/kWh
19.24 cents/kWh
15.30 cents/day
15.30 cents/day
12 cents/kWh data
7 cents/kWh data
```

I have written the below formula, but not able to filter the required data (starting cell no.: B2):

```
{=IF(".",(LEFT(B2, MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2))),1))),0))+2),(LEFT(B2, MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2))),1))),0))))}
```

Can anyone help me out with this!

### Expected Result:

```
31.55
49.66
12.84
19.24
15.3
15.3
12
7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little trick [I've seen before](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/l7l9o1/how_do_i_extract_a_specific_valuenumbers_from/gla1dvt/?context=3) on another site. You can try:

Microsoft's 365:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))
```

Or for earlier versions, to drag down:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(A1,ROW($1:$100)))
```

Or if you are less confident about the lenght being under a 100 chars:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))))
```

***Sidenote:*** We also went from using a volatile `INDIRECT()` to a semi-volatile `INDEX()`.

---

***Note:*** this is for locales where a dot is the decimal delimiter, add an nested `SUBSTITUTE()` in there for when your locale uses a comma:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",","),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))
```

---

*Short explaination:*

The idea here is that we iterate from the left of our string feeding an array of lenghts to the 2nd parameter of `LEFT()`. The minus in front of the `LEFT()` will turn all values into either negative numbers or errors that will be ignored. Since `LOOKUP()` cannot find the *positive* number 1 from the 1st parameter it will return the next smallest value from the resulting array. The only thing to be done then is turning the negative into a positive with the leading minus in front of the whole formula. Since `LOOKUP()` is a native CSE-formula you do not have to confirm it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty but it works.  Copy the following formula down.

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"c/kWh",""),"cents/kWh",""),"cents/day",""),"data","")
```

[image: POC]

A better solution as it can handle any text removal is the solution presented by JvdV.  This is just demonstrating an alternative approach if you have limited text options to be stripped.